# Problem Regarding Quantization in Goodstein's Book

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions, discrete

This question regards what is stated at *page 65, Goodstein, States of Matter*.
We want to consider a free particle in one dimension, with movements restricted to a line of lenght $L$; so in practice we have a particle in an infinite square well, am I right?
Well, it is then stated that the energy and the wave vector of the particle, in this situation, are quantized; ok, no problem here.
**But:** then the book goes on stating that:
$$k=\frac{2\pi}{L}n \ \ \ ; \ \ \ n=0,\pm 1 , \pm 2 , ... \tag{1}$$
**This seems wrong to me.** In fact we have a particle with hamiltonian:
$$H=\frac{\hbar ^ 2 k^2}{2m}$$
It's wave function should be:
$$\psi (x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}$$
but it's in an infinite square well, with walls at 0 and at $L$, for example, so $\psi(x)$ should be zero at $x=0$ and $x=L$, so $\psi(x)$ (using Euler Formula) should be a $\sin$, to have it be equal to zero in $x=0$:
$$\psi(x)=C\sin(kx)$$
now the behaviour of $\psi(x)$ in $x=0$ is all good. We now have to impose that $\psi(L)=0$, so:
$$Csin(kL)=0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ kL=\pi n$$
because of course the $\sin$ is zero only when its argument ($\theta$) is equal to: $\theta = 0,\pm\pi,\pm2\pi,...$ So we get:
$$k=\frac{\pi}{L}n \ \ \ ; \ \ \ n=0,\pm 1 ,\pm 2 ,...$$
**So (1) is wrong!** *But:* this way (1) of writing the quantization of the wave vector is present not only in the *Goodstein* but also in many of my lecture notes, so I am starting to think that I must have made a mistake somewhere and that (1) is indeed correct..
I have heard that **maybe** all this has something to do with PBC (*Periodic Boundary Condition*), but *Goodstein* doesn't talk about this topic and I have no idea on what those are and why they should matter..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Periodic boundary conditions state $$\psi(x)=\psi(x+L)\tag{1'}.$$ Goodstein says "[...] it (the particle) has equal probability of being anywhere on the line", which would not be true if we take $\psi(0)=\psi(L)=0$. You can see that with the condition ($1'$), $k$ takes the values that he claims.

Edit:

In this particular case, I don't know what are the motivations to consider PBC appart from what I already said, that Goodstein is asking the particle to be anywhere on the line with the same probability. More information about its use [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323776/periodic-vs-open-boundary-conditions?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355732/what-is-the-logic-behind-box-normalization-and-periodic-boundary-condition?noredirect=1&lq=1).

As OP says, the wave function is

$$\psi(x)=Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}.$$

Imposing $(1')$, we have

$$Ae^{ikx}+Be^{-ikx}=Ae^{ikx}e^{ikL}+Be^{-ikx}e^{-ikL}$$
$$Ae^{ikx}\Big(1-e^{ikL}\Big)+Be^{-ikx}\Big(1-e^{-ikL}\Big)=0\tag{2'}.$$

As $e^{ikx}$ and $e^{-ikx}$ are independent functions, if we want ($2'$) to hold for any $A$ and $B$,

$$e^{\pm ikL}=1\,\,\Rightarrow\,\,k=\frac{2\pi}{L}n\,\,\,\text{with  }n=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$$

Comment: Your answer is not helpful. Why do we have to use periodic boundary conditions? Why shouldn't $\psi$ go to zero if we have infinite potential walls? And even if we accept your (1') how can we derive the form of the eigenfunctions? And why do we get the values with $2\pi$? Your answer is too short and it assumes a lot of knowledge on this topic, and  if I would have this knowledge then I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: @Noumeno This answer seems fine and correct to me. There's not a lot of context in the question, but often periodic boundary conditions are used in studying crystals (ie, periodic arrays of nuclei with electrons either bound to a nucleus or hopping between nuclei). Periodic boundary conditions would be exactly correct for an infinite crystal, and are a good approximation in the bulk of a crystal away from the edges.