# How to derive the Fermion generating function formally from operator formalism?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, hilbert-space, path-integral, fermions

The generating functionals for fermions is:
$$Z[\bar{\eta},\eta]=\int\mathcal{D}[\bar{\psi}(x)]\mathcal{D}[\psi(x)]e^{i\int d^4x
[\bar{\psi}(i\not \partial -m+i\varepsilon)\psi+\bar{\eta}\psi+\bar{\psi}\eta]}.$$

I don't understand how this can be derived formally from operator formalism.

For Scalar field: $$Z[0]=1=\langle 0 \vert 0 \rangle = \int\mathcal{D}\Phi(x)e^{iS},$$ which is rigorously done by interpolating complete basis $$\int d\Phi(x)\vert \Phi\rangle\langle \Phi\vert=1$$
and
$$\int d\Pi(x)\vert \Pi\rangle\langle \Pi\vert=1$$ which makes sense since $\hat{\phi}(x)$ and $\hat{\pi}(x)$are hermitian operators and their eigenstates supposedly span a complete basis of the Hilbert space. We also have $$[\hat{\phi}(x),\hat{\pi}(y)]=i\delta^3(x-y).$$ These are sufficient to give a path integral expression for $\langle 0 \vert 0 \rangle $.

**None of above applies to the Fermion case. For a start, the Dirac Spinor is not even Hermitian, making it questionable to insert any complete basis of field eigenstates.**

Both full derivation and reference to relevant materials will be appreciated.

Comment: Briefly speaking, to heuristically perform the derivation of the path integral from the operator formalism for fermions, one uses [fermionic coherent states](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=fermionic+coherent+states). The main idea is still the same: Insert infinitely many completeness relations. 

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531603/2451) related Phys.SE post.

Comment: @Qmechanic thanks! My textbook completely skipped this part. Is it true that the path integral for complex scalar field is also coherent states path integral?

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Briefly speaking, to heuristically perform the derivation of the path integral from the operator formalism for fermions, one uses [fermionic coherent states](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=fermionic+coherent+states). The main idea is still the same: Insert infinitely many completeness relations.

See also [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531603/2451) related Phys.SE post.